# tns test android fails for the first time, then succeeds on second execution

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine, nativescript

`tns test android` fails with

> com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: \"./config\",
>   relative to: /app/tns_modules/nativescript-unit-test-runner.

But it executes successfully when run the second time.

Answer (score 1):

The tns system sometimes gets confused and does not switch the files properly when it is rewriting them to start your app in a test mode.  I have seen this error before, and it seems to be random when it hits.

One way you can mitigate it; is if you use the [NativeScript-LiveEdit](http://github.com/NathanaelA/NativeScript-LiveEdit) plugin, it has the ability to automatically relaunch your app in test mode if you change any of the test files, and then it will automatically relaunch your app in app mode when you change any app related files.

Disclaimer: I wrote the NS-LiveEdit plugin.